# Check Location Of UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, cgpoint

I need to make a condition check for if one of my imageView's ends up off the screen. In other words I was hoping someone could help me set up an if statement to see where my imageView is on the screen

```
if previewImageView......... (something here)
```

Thank You!

Comment: if (yourImageView.frame.maxX > self.view.frame.size.width){}

Comment: I guess I'm curious why you need to know this. (1) If you want a scroll bar when needed, consider a `UIScrollView`? (2) If you are concerned about having an image fit on the screen, consider using the correct `contentMode`? (3) Are you facing some sort of layout issue that can easily be resolved using auto layout? The truth is, there are *many* alternatives to (a) finding out if an image view is on the screen, and (b) MOST importantly, you've shown us no code of any other specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `min` and `max` values of the `frame` of your view on both axis is bigger/smaller than the same properties of your `ViewController`s `view`.

```
if imageView.frame.maxX > self.view.frame.size.width {
    print("Image goes out of screen on the right")
} else if imageView.frame.minX < 0 {
    print("Image goes out of screen on the left")
} else if imageView.frame.maxY > self.view.frame.size.height {
    print("Image goes out of screen on the top")
} else if imageView.frame.minY < 0 {
    print("Image goes out of screen at the bottom")
}
```

If you don't care which direction it goes out of the view, you can merge all statements into one:

```
if imageView.frame.maxX > self.view.frame.size.width || imageView.frame.minX < 0 || imageView.frame.maxY > self.view.frame.size.height || imageView.frame.minY < 0 {
        print("Image out of bounds")
    }
```

Comment: Hey Dave! Thanks for the help! This all makes sense, my only issue is with the first one my Xcode gives me a syntax error when I punch in self.view, so I cannot get the width of the entire view. Do you think it's because I am working in a subclass of UIView rather than UIViewController?

Comment: Yes, that's why. You just have to plug the name of your `superview` in place of `self.view`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (yourImageView.frame.maxX > self.view.frame.size.width){
       //will enter if image not all inside the screen 
    }
```

Note that you can change self.view to whatever parent the image is on.

Hope this helps!